# Can I login via one Google account when I am logged in GMail under a second account?

Tags: support, login

I have two mail-id's

1. primary@gmail.com (professional mail-id)
2. secondary@gmail.com (personal mail-id)

I browse through Internet Explorer v11 as Firefox v30.0 freezes up quite often and is quite slow to respond.

primary@gmail.com is my primary mail through which I have logged into Gmail.

secondary@gmail.com is my secondary mail (through which I regularly log into Stack Overflow).

Now I have logged into Gmail through primary@gmail.com and check my mails. Later I shift to Stack Overflow (which requires secondary@gmail.com) and click login to check the latest posts. For which I click log-out under the permissions page as it is not my secondary@gmail.com account.

After logging through secondary@gmail.com automatically my primary@gmail.com is also logged out in Gmail. For which I need to manually re-enter my primary mail id and password. Can't I avoid this  kind of situation without any secondary browser?

Please avoid answers such as shift to a second browser as my second browser hangs up often and also answers such as log out from primary@gmail.com as I regularly check mail from it.

Comment: You can add a different login method to you stack overflow profile, that way you would be independent of gmail

Comment: @HugoRune wouldn't adding a different login method will lose my benefits and rep of my gmail related account.

Comment: @user285oo6 I think you should ask this on Meta. Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Actually [posting on a child meta is absolutely fine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89232/182796)

Comment: @HugoRune Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Use Outlook or a similar program to check your emails so you can just remain logged into your secondary Google account all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [add a different login method](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) to your stackoverflow profile. Doing so means you can log in to the **same acccount** with **different credentials**.

Adding a different login method is different from creating a new acccount. All your relevant data on stackoverflow is tied to the account, adding a new login will not cause you to loose any reputation, questions, or favorites.

Answer (score 4):

You can log into multiple gmail accounts at once enabling you to be logged in as both your pirmary and secondary accounts. Once you have this set up when you go to a Google site you you can switch between accounts as needed. In the case of the Stack Exchange network when you go to sign up/sign in it will let you chose between all of the Google accounts that you are signed into so you can sign in as your secondary account without the need to associate your primary account also if you don't want to. This is what I use on my personal computer in goggle chrome.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en

Comment: I want to emphasize that this answer helps even outside stack exchange.